# Bill reading Shakespeare and Maureen singing Schubert satisfy/satisfies me

Tags: verb-agreement, syntactic-analysis

Which verb form is grammatically correct here? My intuition says 'satisfy' but a textbook I'm reading says otherwise (Core Syntax: A Minimalist Approach. If interested, a legal copy is available [here](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/David_Adger/publication/245800837_Core_syntax_A_minimalist_approach/links/54a11efa0cf256bf8bae26c2.pdf)).

Answer (score 7):

This is actually interesting. I started to write a flip comment but then I thought about it a little more.

The truth is, it could go either way, depending on what you mean.

If you mean the two things are independently satisfying, use satisfy. Using A and B for shorthand, we get:

> A satisfies me. B satisfies me. But A and B *satisfy* me.

If you mean both conditions happening at the same time are necessary for your satisfaction, creating a unitary satisfaction which would fail the satisfaction test if either were missing, choose *satisfies*.

> A verbing and B verbing *satisfies* me.

Comment: "I started to write a flip comment but then I thought about it a little more." Same thing happened to me. +1 for not waiting for someone else to answer.

Comment: Heck, you could even say "Bill reading Shakespeare and Maureen singing Schubert back to back satisfies me."